# Display logged in authors' posts in recent posts widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several authors on a WordPress site. On the recent posts widget, I want to display the  latest posts from each author. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You create your own widget which only selects the posts by that author. You'll use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) in the widget to do so. You have the full source code of the recent posts widget to copy and learn from.